# reactjs Route Not Found The requested URL

Tags: reactjs, apache, .htaccess, routes, refresh

I am using Apache 2.2 to host my reactjs app ... in my App.js I have this code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router,
        Route,
        Link,
        Switch,
        Redirect
 } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Cat from './components/Cat';

const NoMatch = ({ location }) => (
  <div>
        <h3>No match for <code>{location.pathname}</code> can be found.</h3>
  </div>
)

class App extends Component {
  render()
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/cat" component={Cat} />
          <Route component={NoMatch} />
        </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I then use npm run build and everything in my build folder is moved to my DocumentRoot folder /var/www/html/home

In this /var/www/html/home i also have a .htaccess file and in that I have

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]
  RewriteRule ^ ./index.html
```

When i go to /Home it is fine and when i hit refresh it is ok. but then i click a link and it brings me to /cat and again it is fine but then when i refresh it shows

Not Found The requested URL /cat was not found on this server.

Has anyone come across this issue ? I see so much online about the .htaccess file fixing the issue but it has not worked for me at all

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem on the server, run npm run build, create a folder with the compiled project, inside build create the .htaccess file with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ ./index.html
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you.
So adding the .htaccess file with the above (Diego. Carrera's code)  in the file uploaded to the root of the domain hosting folder did the trick for me.

Comment: solved my issue